# Modifying a char* by pointer in a function gives a crash

Tags: c, arrays, function, char, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm fairly new to C and I'm trying to work out dynamic memory allocation for reading from a file. At least I think that's what I'm doing.

Anyway, this code works:

```
int readfromfile(FILE *filepointer)
{
    size_t size = 2;
    char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    int character = 0;
    size_t counter = 0;
    while((character = fgetc(filepointer)) != EOF)
    {
        str = (char *) realloc(str, size);
        str[counter] = (char) character;
        size ++;
        counter++;

    }
    str[counter] = '\0';
    printf("+%s+", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

And this code does not:

```
int main()
{
    char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    ...
    readfromfile(ifpointer, &str);
}

int readfromfile(FILE *filepointer, char **str)
{
    size_t size = 2;
    int character = 0;
    size_t counter = 0;
    while((character = fgetc(filepointer)) != EOF)
    {
        *str = (char *) realloc(*str, size);
        *str[counter] = (char) character;
        size ++;
        counter++;
    }
    str[counter] = '\0';
    printf("+%s+", *str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot understand why because as far as I understand I'm sending a pointer to the location of the char array to the function and accessing the data everytime. The compilers shows no error messages, it just loops through once and on the second loop crashes after the `realloc` every time. The character assigned to the first value is garbage too.

I have spent an age trying to get this to worked and done a lot of research so I apologise if I've missed a solution but I'm truly stuck at this point.

Comment: never cast the result of malloc.

Comment: It reallocates memory when it adds more characters though does it not?

And as for freeing memory, my apologies that was just testing to check it had been freed, edited out now.

Comment: you don't need to add a cast for `malloc`

Comment: @JJJ, yes, I had not seen the `realloc` part, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a crash because

```
*str[counter] = (char) character;
```

is the same as

```
*(str[counter]) = (char) character;
```

as opposed to

```
(*str)[counter] = (char) character;
```

which is actually what you wanted. Read [Operator Precedence on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence). You'll find that `[]` has more precedence than the `*` (dereference operator).

Also, the cast here, as well as in the calls to `realloc` and `malloc`, is unnecessary. Don't forget to check the return value of `realloc`, `malloc` etc to see if they were successful in allocating memory.

Now, you have another problem: `free(str);` in the second code should be `free(*str);`. Note that after `*str` has been freed from the function, you aren't supposed to read or write into this memory location from `main` as it has now become invalid for you to tamper with.

Comment: Thank you so much! I cannot believe missing one set of brackets caused me this much trouble, I'll definitely have to give that piece a read.

Comment: @JJJ the difference between the two operations may seem not very strong, but its two completly different operations, so ofcourse the two will cause two different results.

Comment: @Cool Guy Ah thanks, got rid of the cast now and I'm about to add in the checks for realloc/malloc too.

Answer (score 0):

in your `int readfromfile(FILE *filepointer, char **str)` the parameter `char **str` is actually the same as `char *str[]`, which means `**str` is expecting an array of char pointers. however you're passing to it `char *str` which is just an array of `char`

when you use readfromfile(...) you should do it this way (something like...):

```
char *str[2] = {"some char array", "another char array"};
readfromfile(ifpointer, str);
```

or:

```
char *a = "this char array";
char **str = &a[0];
readfromfile(ifpointer, str);
```

you'll get the idea...

Comment: "_which means `**str` is expecting an array of char pointers_" -- No. It expects a pointer to a pointer to a `char` (a `char**`) "_however you're passing to it `char *str` which is just an array of `char`_" -- No. The OP is passing `&str` which is a `char**`, exactly what the second argument of `readfromfile` requires.